# Filling dataframe matching regex from another one

Tags: r, dataframe, fill

I'm not really an R pro and I can't find a quick way to accomplish this task.

EDIT: I tried to simplify the dataframes in order to be clearer.

I have a big dataframe (`df1`) with 716K entries and the following columns (sample):

```
   author_id           text                         vote_int
 1 2898475609          #please #voteyes             NA
 2 2163623162          help and #voteno             NA
```

and another one (`df2`) like this:

```
   tag                vote_int
 1 voteno             0
 2 voteyes            1
```

The column `text` in `df1` may contain a hashtag. I want to fill the `df1$vote_int`, matching the hashtag in `df2$tag` with a regex, with the value in `df1$vote_int`.

The expected output looks like this:

```
   author_id           text                         vote_int
 1 2898475609          #please #voteyes             1
 2 2163623162          help and #voteno             0
```

I know I can match the hashtags using `str_detect` and did it with a for loop, but takes ages. I'm sure there is a quick way of doing it but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Can you give the expected output for your samples above? I'm having trouble following. Can you also use `dput(head(df1)` and `dput(head(df2))` to make the example more reproducible?

Comment: I provided the expected output. Tried to run `dput`, but the output is not really neat for posting here, the dataframe is broad a some entries are huge

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what regex you are using to detect hashtags (replace my naive one below with the one that is working for you).

However, once you extract it into a column called `tag`, you can do a join (below is left join to retain all rows of `df1`, but you could change to `inner_join` or `right_join`, depending on your needs)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

left_join(
  df1 %>% select(-vote_int) %>%  mutate(tag=str_extract_all(text, "(?<=#)\\w+")) %>% unnest(tag),
  select(df2, tag, vote_int),
  by="tag"
)
```

Comment: Hi, what should RT be? I tried to replace it with the column name but didn't really work

Comment: i've updated the code based on your new example data (by the way, there is no point having an NA column called `vote_int` in df1, so you can see that I drop it. Also I now see that df2 has changed, and no longer has the hash character (`#`) in `tag` column. Finally, I note that df1 entries can have multple hash tags in the same tweet, so I use `str_extract_all` and I `unnest` to make multiple rows